# Using liquibases init project from gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, liquibase

Liquibase has [init project](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/init/project.html) subcommand to get started with Liquibase.

Is it possible to run this command via the [Liquibase Gradle Plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.liquibase.gradle)?

If not, is it possible to generate a skeleton / empty `databaseChangeLog` file from Gradle script? Which I can use as my root changelog file to reference other generated changelogs.

Answer (score 0):

I asked some of our development team about this, and they said that

- Running init project with the Gradle plugin is untested
- Even though we didn't test it, it might still work. Did you try running it yourself?
- Are you looking for something to create an xml file with just the xsd headers and root element? They provided the XML below, if that's the case.

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd"
>

</databaseChangeLog>
```